# counter variable is holding 2 values on 2nd pass of the function

Tags: javascript

I'm making a typing game. When multiple players play the game it runs through the same set of functions again. I'm using the variable j as a counter to advance words when they are typed correctly. For some reason, on the second pass on each upkeystroke, it logs j = 1 & j = whatever the value of the previous players last word + 1 is. When each player plays, I want each set of words they are typing to be the same, so that it is fair. I can't figure out why this is happening or even how the variable has 2 values at the same time?!?!?

What gives?

Here's the code in question, but there's a bunch of callbacks that could be involved, although the only place this variable is called is inside this function.

```
//advances ship on correct typing
function runRace() {
  timer();
  var j = 1;
  //BUG HERE !! Works fine on first iteration but on second 
  //iterations value jumps beteween 1 and whatever the next 
  //one is. It's like on every keystroke it reassigns var j
  //back to 1, then back to the element number it was on 
  //last time
  //!!! j has 2 values !!!it's keeping the value from the 
  //prior running of run race  
  $(document).keyup(function(e){
    var targetWord = $(".toType").text();
    var typedWord = $("#word").val();
    //while (j < gameWords.length){
      console.log("j = " + j);
      if(typedWord === targetWord){
        $(".player").css({left: "+=15px",});
        targetWord = $(".toType").text(gameWords[j]);
        $("#word").val("");
        j++;
      }else {
        return
      };
    //}
  });
}
```

If you need to see the rest of the code to figure this out, it's here. Eventhough it's not running right on jsfiddle for reason, it works other then the bug, locally https://jsfiddle.net/ujsr139r/1/

Comment: Each time you call `runRace()` your code is creating a listener on `keyup` - so the next time it runs there are 2 keyups firing, then 3 on the 3rd etc. You should only have the listener once.

Comment: that makes total sense! now I just have to figure out how to refactor it to only call it once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i mentioned in my comment you're creating multiple listeners everytime `runRace()` is called.

You could try something like this instead (please note, this isn't the best way to do this, i'm just demoing. Global variables like `j` in this case aren't a clever idea.:

```
var j=1; // global because its outside of your function
$(function(){
  $(document).keyup(function(e){
    var targetWord = $(".toType").text();
    var typedWord = $("#word").val();
    //while (j < gameWords.length){
      console.log("j = " + j);
      if(typedWord === targetWord){
        $(".player").css({left: "+=15px",});
        targetWord = $(".toType").text(gameWords[j]);
        $("#word").val("");
        j++;
      }else {
        return
      };
    //}
  });
});

//advances ship on correct typing
function runRace() {
  j = 1;
  timer();  
}
```

Comment: yeah I was trying that, I just stuck the event listner in the document ready, but that made some other functions fail. I'll try it this way and see if it works.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks!! This had been bugging me for close to 2 hours now. Thanks again!

Comment: No worries. Just bare in mind global variables can bite you  if you're not careful.

Comment: yeah, I know, but I use them all over the place in this one, because I need to keep passing info through different functions and I thought it's be easier then calling them trough arguements. I think I use 6 globals here. So 1 more isn't gonna kill me.